# Rails 3.1.rc4 scss partial has mixins not available to main stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I have a scss partial file `"_sharedBase.scss"` to store mixins and other variables, so that it can then be used in other stylesheets in the system.

I break my styles up into `"common.css.scss"` (for constantly applied attributes like fonts families etc) and `"Screen.css.scss"` for screen media and `"print.css.scss"` for print media so I can arrange different layouts etc for screen ann print.

At the top of each of the 3 main files I have `"@import "sharedBase.scss";`  This appears to be working as in the rails server console I see the request for `common.css`, and I see (2x) messages to compile `_sharedBase.scss`, but then I get an error compiling `common.css.scss` it says it can't find mixin.

Have searched and found info like remove media to prevent this, but still no joy.  Is there anyway I can prevent rails from compiling scss to css for the partial?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on 3.1.0.rc4. What I did was to create a file called _mixins.css.scss in the assets/stylesheet directory. Then on top of each .css.scss file I add @import "mixins.css.scss";

Would be nicer to be able to just set it one place, but for now this solves the problem.